# How do I log a Canadian NR4 form to my income taxes

Tags: united-states, income-tax, canada, form-1099

I have stock in a Canadian company whose US branch I used to work for. They mailed me an NR4 form for my interest last year. I'm trying to fill out my tax forms this year and the advice I keep seeing is to put it down as a 1099-DIV as 1b income after currency conversion. Do I put the same value down for 1a to keep the tax software from complaining?

Comment: What's the income code?

Comment: @littleadv: 09 is the income code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Income code 09 is dividends, so yes - it is the same as line 1 of the US form 1099-DIV.

1a or 1b however depends on whether the requirements for qualified dividends are met. If they're met - its 1b, if not - 1a. These are treated and taxed differently.

See here on what are the [qualification requirements](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch08.html#en_US_2013_publink1000171584). Note that Canada has a tax treaty with the US making Canadian corporations "[qualified foreign corporations](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch08.html#en_US_2013_publink1000171592)".